# name clash with generics

Tags: java, generics

I am not sure what is going on here, since I am implementing this interface specifying the type correctly, but am getting this error..

basic TelemetryDataType definition:

```
public interface TelemetryData<T> extends Iterable<T> {

}
```

interface declaration:

```
public interface DataAccessor<R, T> {
    T access(TelemetryData<R> dataStore) throws IOException;
}
```

implementation class:

```
static abstract class A<R, T> implements DataAccessor<R, T> {
    @Override
    public final T access(TelemetryData<R> dataStore) throws IOException {
        //implementation    
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:
error: name clash: access(TelemetryData) in A and access(TelemetryData) in DataAccessor have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

The implementation class implements the interface using specified generic types which should solve the type erasure problem and the definition of the method implementation is the exact signature (except for final which should be irrelevant)

Any insight in to what the issue is here as this looks correct to me..
Source/Target are 1.7 using JDK 1.8 to compile.

EDIT:
This is weird, I put the problem code into a single file for a SCCE and it builds.. This makes me wonder if maven/netbeans has some junk left behind somewhere..

Comment: Can you make absolutely sure that you're importing the same TelemetryData in each file?

Comment: Yes, I even cleaned both projects, removed them from the maven repo then attempted to rebuild. - Also, DataAccessor is defined in the same TelemetryData source file

Comment: Please create a minimal example which reproduces your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the example.. the only thing I can add is a basic definition of the TelemetryData interface..

Comment: *"which reproduces your problem"* ... your example doesn't do that. It misses necessary classes, the class structure, import statements and the outer class of `A`.

Comment: Yeah, and I just tried a SCCE... and it builds.. so it may be a maven/netbeans clutter issue with clean not cleaning or junk left behind..